# When can a tomato plant come back from the "dead"?

Tags: tomatoes

I've heard stories of people who have had seemingly-dead tomato plants which they left alone and the plant grew back. How can I tell if my plant is dead as opposed to merely in poor shape? Is there anything I can do to encourage it?

This was the plant a few days ago; since then the brown wilted part has been spreading down the stem. It had some damage to the stem in a storm, losing the top portion with the leaves.

[image: The plant]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well it isn't dead, as the stem seems quite green. If you are interested from a botany/plant physiology standpoint let it grow.

There will be nodes where there used to be leaves. These will regrow new branches, but if you are in a hurry for tomatoes, go out and buy a new one, the biggest one that you can find cheaply.

Comment: The image is a few days old; it's become more brown each day. Is that a bad sign? Should I pinch off the dead part?

Comment: that is a bad sign... maybe check the roots, make sure the soil smells good, sometimes you can overwater and make the soil anaerobic, will smell like a swamp.